# Wordpress: Call to undefined function get_header(),get_header() run in index.php but this not run in amthuc.php

Tags: header

I meet the error,that not index.php, the error in page include index, that is name amthuc.php. Who can help me? please, thanks so much :)
get_header() run in index.php but not run in amthuc.php

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas03_data01/11/2436011/html/wp-content/themes/pnac/amthuc.php on line 1

Comment: Welcome. You need to expand on your issue. We neither know what you are trying to achieve, nor do we know what your coding looks like. Please provide these things in your question so that you can get an adequate answer

Comment: get_header run in index.php but not run in amthuc.php